# Is there a keyboard shortcut to revert individual changes in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

When a file has changes compared to the version checked-out from the version control system (subversion and cvs in my case), I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> to jump between those changes. Sometimes I want to revert some of these changes (but not all the changes in the file). I can do that by using the mouse and clicking the little revert-icon with the green arrow, but is there a way to do it from the keyboard (without using the mouse)?

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 7.0.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign a hotkey to the **Rollback** action in **Settings | Keymap**, it's not assigned by default.

**UPDATE:** it appears that the Rollback action actually calls Revert for the whole file. I've submitted [IDEA-26912](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-26912) for this, please Watch/Vote.

Comment: I have tried Rollback, but it only seems to roll back **all** the changes in the file. What I am looking for is to be able to selectively revert individual changes as I get to them. Is this possible?

Comment: You are right, it doesn't work as expected. I've submitted the new YouTrack issue.

Comment: This is an old question, but it has been fixed. You can now assign it to the key you want.

Comment: Even though issue seems to be marked "fixed", the shortcut is not there. I'm not so sure people understood we wanted to revert the current line as opposed to reverting the whole file. I've been using the mouse for this one too.

Answer (score 5):

You can set in **Setting** | **Keymap** and select `Version Control Systems` in the keymap list and set the shortcut,but `revert` action in my subversion settings was set default to **Ctrl+Alt+Z**

Comment: Independent of VCS - was also default shortcut for git

Answer (score 2):

Rollback no longer reverts the whole file and can be assigned a keyboard shortcut.  See [this comment](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-48594#comment=27-604776).  Verified in IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.6 Ultimate.